# Groovy range toString() behaviour

Tags: groovy, tostring

I was messing around in the Groovy shell and just happened to try
`0..0.toString()` I was expecting this to return something like `"[0]"`, as `0..0 == [0]`, but it gave me an array of integers from 0 to 48. What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ascii code for the character "0" is 48. With `0..0.toString()` you are asking for a list/array staring with the integer `0` (thus it will be a collection of integers), ending with `0.toString()`, which groovy succeeds to interpret as an integer by taking its ascii value.

Comment: Try (0..0).toString()